# How does one show (not tell) community SysAdmin work they've done?

Tags: resume, volunteering

As a developer and SysAdmin, I do a lot of community work (like online community). With development, I can host my home projects on a repo like Github to show it to potential employers. I can link to Github on my LinkedIn, etc. Telling people (like "oh I coded x and y") doesn't seem as useful as actually showing people.

So how do I accomplish this for my SysAdmin work? I want to show, not tell.

Examples I've done:

- Volunteer host (Linux SysAdmin) for various MUDs in the community
- Webhost for various personal projects I've created
- SysAdmin for revival of a game called "Phantasia 4"
- SysAdmin for my own MUD server for 10+ years

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

In a sysadmin role, the output is really in the metrics. Do you have metrics you can show?

Eg.

- Ran X servers for Y price at Z load
- Had X uptime/downtime
- Personal response time was X
- Increased efficiency by X
- Etc

Answer (score 0):

Since a SysAdmin doesn't have a "thing" to show off, have you considered getting testimonials or references from the group members where you are an admin?

If that's not enough, maybe screen captures? If it's in a resume, you aren't going to be "showing" people anything, really (other than links to things).

Comment: Testimonials are tough for most of what I've done. If I run a MUD server for my MUD, my players aren't really going to understand it runs on a server and so I'm not sure who could give a testimonial. Screenshots I'm not sure either. If I was hiring someone and they showed me a screen capture of a SSH login I don't think my opinion would really jump up much? This is tough.

Answer (score -2):

If you have code you're proud of, you might consider explaining the goal and success of the code you wrote, rather than showing them the code itself, and then explain your ability to come up with, and implement useful solutions.

The reason I say this, is that most companies will most likely not have their GitHub repositories open to those outside the company, so your links might be useless.

Comment: -1: Does not answer the OPs question about showcasing SysAdmin work.